# MultiValueDictKeyError: 'content'

Tags: python, django

i'm going to make the todo list using django...i did some code...but it throws an multiplevaluekeyerror

i tried  c = request.POST.get('content', False)
but it gives always as False value

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import TodoItem

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def work(request):
    all_todo_items = TodoItem.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'work.html', {'all_items': all_todo_items})

def addTodo(request):
    c = request.POST['content']
    new_item = TodoItem(content = c)
    new_item.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/work/')

def deleteTodo(request, todo_id):
    item_to_delete = TodoItem.objects.get(id=todo_id)
    item_to_delete.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/work/')
```

work.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/work.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'images/list.png' %}" type="image/png">
    <title>Tasks</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container justify-content-center wrap1">
        <div class="text-center heading">
            <p><u>write your everyday task here!!!<u></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <ul style="list-style: none; color: #1b0573; font-weight: bold;" class="text-center">
      {% for todo_item in all_items %}
        <li>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              {{ todo_item.content }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              {{ todo_item.date_created }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <form action="/deleteTodo/{{ todo_item.id }}" method="post" style="display: inline;">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>

        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-11">
          <form action="/addTodo/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="write your task" name="content">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">
            <form action="/addTodo/" method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('work/', views.work, name = 'work'),
    path('addTodo/', views.addTodo, name = 'work'),
    path('deleteTodo/<int:todo_id>/', views.deleteTodo, name = 'work'),
]
```

i was expecting no errors...but it throws an multiplevaluekeyerror

raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'content'

Comment: why you have two `<form action="/addTodo/" method="post">` ? one of them haven't `input` tag with `name="content"`

Comment: i've used one form tag for backend and another one for dispaly on the web page.. the button tag just below the input tag....is going to add all the items...but it is not doing so

Comment: i'm not get what you mean about "form tag for backend and another one for display on web page" . you are using form tag to submit new task right?

Comment: yes...okkk my bad

Answer (score 0):

you need submit first `<form>` that you have in your code that include `<input name="content">` so in `view` can using `request.POST["conten"] to get value of`` . try this:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-11">
          <form action="/addTodo/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="write your task" name="content">
              <input type="submit" value="submit new task">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: why can't use button tag

Comment: <button class="btn btn-outline-success" name="content"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>

Comment: while pressing the enter it displays the data...but on clicking the button symbol it also display but there is nothing like the invisible line

Comment: you can use `<button type="submit">` too. but you need have `<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="write your task" name="content">` in form that you are submiting so in backned you can use `request.POST['content']` to have content value.

Comment: <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>    i used this but again got the same error

Comment: if i'm using   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" name="content"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>   it throws no error but while pressing the enter it displays the data...but on clicking the button symbol it also display but there is nothing like invisible data

Comment: your problem is that you haven't `<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="write your task" name="content">` in <form> that you are trying to submit it.just replace my code instead of all code belong to `<div class="container">` and tell me what happen if you pressing submit button?